# Azure Search- Is there way to get exact match of words?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

In Azure Search , Is there a way we can get exact match result of multiple words?
If i Search for word "Coca Cola Millenials". Can i get the result from results of azure matching the word "Coca Cola Millenials"

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking if you can search for the phrase "Coca Cola Millenials"? Yes, you can. Surround the phrase with quotes as you did in this question.

From our [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/simple-query-syntax-in-azure-search):

> The phrase operator encloses a phrase in quotation marks. For example,
> while Roach Motel (without quotes) would search for documents
> containing Roach and/or Motel anywhere in any order, "Roach Motel"
> (with quotes) will only match documents that contains that whole
> phrase together and in that order (text analysis still applies).

Hope that helps

Comment: This answer is still valid.